# MotherBoard information with WMI, using mingw

Tags: c++, c, mingw, wmi, motherboard

I am using mingw as a compiler, and i'm trying to get the wmi to work somehow, but the code depends on the

```
wbemidl.h
Wbemuuid.lib
```

how can i avoid using this librariy? For example

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &locator);
```

How can i get CLSID_WbemLocator and IID_IWbemLocator myself? Also i need to somehow define myself the pointers to the COM interface.

```
  IWbemLocator         *locator  = NULL;
  IWbemServices        *services = NULL;
  IEnumWbemClassObject *results  = NULL;
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Declare a variable of type `GUID` called `CLSID_WbemLocator` and initialize it with the correct value.

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvlious :). But how do i get the correct value? Look it up in wbemidl.h? And also what should i do about com pointers? IWbemLocator,IWbemServices etc

Answer (score 2):

I got CLSID_WbemLocator from the registry finding it under WBEMComLocator. Since my app is written in C I initialized the GUID structure so:

```
CLSID CLSID_WbemLocator = {0x4590F811, 0x1D3A, 0x11D0, {0x89, 0x1F, 0, 0xAA, 0, 0x4B, 0x2E, 0x24}};
```

With this solved I could run the example given under [How to obtain data from WMI using a C Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431103/how-to-obtain-data-from-wmi-using-a-c-application) I think you have to use the libraries you mentioned. Why not? MinGW provides those libraries.