# How to get a list of all attached virtual disks in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is there a way to retrieve a list of all virtual disks attached on a Windows machine? I mean all paths to VHD/VHDX mounted by disk manager.

There is an undocumented function `GetAllAttachedVirtualDiskPhysicalPaths` that does exactly that, however it's not available in Windows 8 (only in 8.1). I need Win 8 support.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stacking For Heap for the hint - with API monitoring I figured that Diskpart uses VDS API for that purpose, namely `IVdsVdProvider`. Just built and tested the code - it works fine.

Similar approach is used here, with code samples:

[Retrieving virtual disk file name from disk number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755458/retrieving-virtual-disk-file-name-from-disk-number/2892042#2892042)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of direct c++ calls, assuming you don't know the VD handles but want to get all mounted disks not created or handled by your own code. There is a rough way to do it by running a

```
  diskpart
  list vdisk
```

script and pipe the result into a text file, which you can then parse with c++ to get the list.

Comment: this internally called `IVdsVdProvider::QueryVDisks` - always better call api and comiterfaces direct yourself