# How can I get a listing of all drives on Windows using golang?

Tags: go

I would like my program to iterate through all drives on a Windows system and search for a particular file type. Right now, I can run the program and pass it a drive letter to start from, but I want it to search on all drives automatically. Currently, I would need to do something like this:

```
C:\> program.exe C:
C:\> program.exe D:
C:\> program.exe E:
```

I want the program to get a list of all drives and iterate through all of them without the user having to specify the drive letter. Is this possible using Go?

Similar to this question [Listing All Physical Drives (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350641/listing-all-physical-drives-windows) but using Go instead of C.

Comment: Why not `for _, drive in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" { /* try some op on drive and continue on failure */ }`?

Comment: Use cgo to use the C API from Go.

Comment: @Volker I was looking for a nicer way?

Comment: @rightfold Thanks, but I'd prefer using standard go packages and not C.

Comment: @roartechs That is as nice as it will get. Your last option would be to use package syscall. Good luck!

Comment: @roartechs There's a decent Go package for this sort of Win32 API stuff: https://github.com/AllenDang/w32 -- https://github.com/AllenDang/w32/blob/master/kernel32.go#L80 is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easist way is write own function with try to open "drive" folder mentioned by Volker.

```
import "os"

func getdrives() (r []string){
    for _, drive := range "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"{
        f, err := os.Open(string(drive)+":\\")
        if err == nil {
            r = append(r, string(drive))
            f.Close()
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Accepted this answer since it doesn't look like there is a nicer way to do it.

Comment: I suspect this might cause delays on some systems, e.g. waiting for a DVD drive to spin up.  I remember how clicking on the A: drive would be slow when no floppy inserted ...

Comment: Doesn't this leave a bunch of open files that need to be `Close()`ed?

Answer (score 14):

You can [call](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsDLLs) the function [`GetLogicalDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972%28VS.85%29.aspx) and match the letters according to the bit map.

Something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    kernel32, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    getLogicalDrivesHandle, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetLogicalDrives")

    var drives []string

    if ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getLogicalDrivesHandle), 0, 0, 0, 0); callErr != 0 {
        // handle error
    } else {
        drives = bitsToDrives(uint32(ret))
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", drives)

}

func bitsToDrives(bitMap uint32) (drives []string) {
    availableDrives := []string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}

    for i := range availableDrives {
        if bitMap & 1 == 1 {
            drives = append(drives, availableDrives[i])
        }
        bitMap >>= 1
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil) lib:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
)

func main() {
    partitions, _ := disk.Partitions(false)
    for _, partition := range partitions {
        fmt.Println(partition.Mountpoint)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can call GetLogicalDriveStrings directly:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    kernel32, err := syscall.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    getLogicalDriveStringsHandle, err := kernel32.FindProc("GetLogicalDriveStringsA")

    buffer := [1024]byte{}
    bufferSize := uint32(len(buffer))
    drives := []string{}

    hr, _, _ := getLogicalDriveStringsHandle.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bufferSize)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer)))
    if hr == 0 {
        fmt.Print("There was an error")
    } else {
        // Deal with the buffer, you need to split it
    }
}
```

Comment: The first param to the Call should be `unitptr(bufferSize)` not `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bufferSize))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `windows` package:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
   "strings"
   "unicode/utf16"
)

func drives() ([]string, error) {
   n, e := windows.GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, nil)
   if e != nil { return nil, e }
   a := make([]uint16, n)
   windows.GetLogicalDriveStrings(n, &a[0])
   s := string(utf16.Decode(a))
   return strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(s, "\x00"), "\x00"), nil
}

func main() {
   a, e := drives()
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   for _, s := range a {
      println(s)
   }
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#GetLogicalDriveStrings