# How do you get the numbers of hard disk (not partitions!) on Windows in golang?

Tags: windows, go, disk-partitioning

This question is different from [How can I get a listing of all drives on Windows using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128148/how-can-i-get-a-listing-of-all-drives-on-windows-using-golang)

I know how get the partitions of hard disk, but what about the numbers of hard disk?
I tried using `diskpark` but don't like it.
[image]

Is there some native go way to implement?

@Dippo saids: I think i found a package : https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi

And it works .
Thx all.

Here the code is.

Gopkg.toml:

`required = ["github.com/stackexchange/wmi"]`

and the go code:

```
func getDiskDrivers() uint8 {
    type Win32_DiskDrive struct {
        Caption      string
        Name         string
        DeviceID     string
        Model        string
        Index        int
        Partitions   int
        Size         int
        PNPDeviceID  string
        Status       string
        SerialNumber string
        Manufacturer string
        MediaType    string
        Description  string
        SystemName   string
    }

    var dst []Win32_DiskDrive

    query := wmi.CreateQuery(&dst, "")
    if err := wmi.Query(query, &dst); err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return 0
    }

    //for key, value := range dst {
    //  log.Println(fmt.Sprintf(`Disk%d: %v`, key+1, value))
    //}

    return uint8(len(dst))
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to know this for Windows only and that the usage of a package is not a problem?

Comment: in windows we can use [`IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968800(v=vs.85).aspx) for get device(disk) number. how/are possible use this in go separate question

Comment: @Dippo yep. I tried to find some pkg of golang, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Zander Wong I also didn't find a package but i did found out that you can enter this one in the command line, this works for win 7, 8 and 10: wmic logicaldisk get name

Comment: @Zander Wong I think i found a package : https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi

Comment: @Dippo this command just list partitions of my hard-disk not the disk numbers.

Comment: @Dippo Thx Very Much!  
I just tested the pkg `wmi`.   
  
It works!
Thx again.

Comment: @Zander Wong You are right that partitios are still visible as a drive, i was wrong because i don't have any partitions. But i found on this website (https://ardamis.com/2012/08/21/getting-a-list-of-logical-and-physical-drives-from-the-command-line/) a query that solves your problem.

Comment: @Dippo  I fount a command line to get hard-disk index.  `$ wmic diskdrive get index`